# OpenCV : how to provide matrix for 'undistort' if I know lens correction factor in Gimp?

Tags: opencv

I'm getting images from an IP camera that have a strong fish-eye effect. I found that in Gimp I can get lines mostly straight by applying the Lens Distortion filter with a "main" value of -30 (all other parameters remain zero).

Now I need to do this ad-hoc using OpenCV. I gathered that the [undistort](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d) function in `imgproc` would be the right thing to call. But how do I generate the correct camera and distortion matrix? I see there is a [calibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga687a1ab946686f0d85ae0363b5af1d7b) function, but it seem you need a PhD in computer vision or so to use it. I have no clue. Since I know the one parameter, there must be a simple way to translate it into the matrix expected by 'undistort'?

Note: I only need the radial distortion coefficients, I'm not interested in the tangential distortion.

Comment: actually there is a sample provided by opencv for [calibration](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp). For that all you need is the list of the images of checkerboard(around 20 should be good). taken by your desired camera. It will give you all the required parameters( distortion coefficients, intrinsic parameters etc.). Then you can use 'undistort' function of opencv to correct your image.

Comment: You  need to change in **default.xml**,  the name of the xml file containing the address of your images, the count of inner squares and their dimension in real world. tadaa you have you required parameters :-)

Comment: @Optimus1072 thanks a lot; I managed to get close; I build opencv from source with the examples, I have 9 chessboard images - I have taken them all "parallel": http://imgur.com/a/JByDH , is this good? - and I run `./bin/cpp-example-calibration -w=5 -h=4 -pt=chessboard -o=amcrest.yml -op -oe image_list.xml`. But this doesn't "output" anything. It opens a window that shows the input images one after another, then quits. I find no file "amcrest.yml", so I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: @Optimus1072 It works now, after understanding that `num-corners = (num-black-squares - 1) * 2`. Can you post your comment as an answer, then I can close the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Generally 15-20 images are considered as good and i guess you will have to use fisheye undistortion function to correct your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample provided by opencv for [calibration](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp). For that all you need is the list of the images of checkerboard(around 20 should be good). taken by your desired camera. It will give you all the required parameters( distortion coefficients, intrinsic parameters etc.). Then you can use 'undistort' function of opencv to correct your image.
You need to change in default.xml,(or you can create your own .xml) the name of the xml file containing the address of your images, the count of inner squares and their dimension in real world.

tadaa you have you required parameters :-)

Comment: Did it now with "just" nine images, looks already pretty accurate.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wonder where that calibration tool comes from. Seems one has to build it from source. This is what I did on Linux:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout -b 3.1.0 3.1.0  # make sure we build that version
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
```

Then to calibrate:

```
./bin/cpp-example-calibration -w=8 -h=6 -o=camera.yml -op -oe -su image_list.xml
```

The `-su` lets you verify how the images look after un-distortion. The `-w` and `-h` parameters take "inner corners" which is not the number of squares in the chess pattern, but rather `(num-black-squares - 1) * 2`.

Here's how the perspective transform is applied in the end, using Scala and JavaCV:

```scala
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.indexer.FloatRawIndexer
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.{opencv_core, opencv_imgcodecs, opencv_imgproc}
import java.io.File

// from the camera_matrix > data part of the yml:
val cameraFocal = 1.4656877976320607e+03
val cameraCX    = 1920.0/2
val cameraCY    = 1080.0/2

val cameraMatrixData = Array[Double](
  cameraFocal, 0.0        , cameraCX,
  0.0        , cameraFocal, cameraCY,
  0.0        , 0.0        , 1.0
)

// from the distortion_coefficients of the yml:
val distMatrixData = Array[Double](
  -4.016824381742e-01, 4.368842493074e-02, 0.0, 0.0, 1.096412142704e-01
)

def run(in: File, out: File): Unit = {
  val matOut  = new Mat
  val camMat  = new Mat(3, 3, opencv_core.CV_32FC1)
  val camIdx  = camMat.createIndexer[FloatRawIndexer]
  for (row <- 0 until 3) {
    for (col <- 0 until 3) {
      camIdx.put(row, col, cameraMatrixData(row * 3 + col).toFloat)
    }
  }
  val distVec = new Mat(1, 5, opencv_core.CV_32FC1)
  val distIdx = distVec.createIndexer[FloatRawIndexer]
  for (col <- 0 until 5) {
    distIdx.put(0, col, distMatrixData(col).toFloat)
  }

  val matIn   = opencv_imgcodecs.imread(in.getPath)
  opencv_imgproc.undistort(matIn, matOut, camMat, distVec)
  opencv_imgcodecs.imwrite(out.getPath, matOut)
}
```