# Stereo Camera calibration using different camera types

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to perform stereo camera calibration, rectification and disparity map generation. It's working fine with normal sample data. However, I'm trying to use the dual cameras on an iPhone 7+, which have different zoom. The telephoto lens has 2X zoom compared to the wide angle camera. I ran the images through the algorithm, and it is succeeding, although with a high error rate. However, when I open up the rectified images, they have a weird spherical look to the edges. The center looks fine. I'm assuming this is due to the cameras having different zoom levels. Is there anything special I need to do to deal with this? Or do I just need to crop any output to the usable undistorted area? Here is what I'm seeing:

[image: Distorted rectified image]

#### EDIT:

I tried using the calibration result from these checkerboard images to rectify an image of some objects, and the rectification was way off, not even close. If I rectify one of my checkerboard images, they are spot on. Any ideas why that happens?

#### EDIT2:

These are what my input images look like that result in the spherical looking output image. They are both taken from the exact same position, the iPhone was mounted to a tripod and I used a bluetooth device to trigger the shutter so the image wouldn't get shaken, my code automatically takes one image with each lens. I took 19 such images from different angles, all images show the full checkerboard. The more zoomed in image is the one that rectified to the top spherical looking image.
[image]
[image]

#### EDIT3:

Here is the disparity map using the calibration I got.

[image]
[image]

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545992/opencv-how-to-provide-matrix-for-undistort-if-i-know-lens-correction-factor/40553720#40553720).

Comment: I already have calibration and rectification working. I compiled this example and have it working: https://github.com/sourishg/stereo-calibration

Comment: @Davido I think (it is only my idea) that if you are performing stereo- calibration (the code seems to do that), you can use only chessboard's points that are seen in both views. If one camera is wide angle, you must have detected points near the border to undistort the image in the correct way. If you have the other camera with 2x zoom, you are able to see the chessboard only in a restricted place of the other camera. At the end, you calibrate the wide angle camera only with pixels detected on its centre, it does not help you to rectify all the image in the correct way, I presume

Comment: @Davido sry I provided you the wrong link, Please check the new link given below. Further, have you tried changing the value of parameter alpha in function stereoRectify. I remember that once I also obtained such results and changing the value of alpha to 0 did the work for me. Please let me know the results you obtain with alpha = -1, alpha=0.5 and alpha =0 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852273/opencv-stereorectify-distorts-image/39854862#39854862).

Comment: "It is succeeding but with a high error rate". What does that mean, exactly? What is your RMS reprojection error? Your result looks like you have a terrible solution for the distortion parameters: you have holes in the images.

Comment: The error rate I'm referring to is the result of the calibrate function I provided the link to. The error I'm getting is .99 for one of the cameras, and .7 for the other. Is that a normal error range for this algorithm? Also, I've been able to get some decent results by cropping both of the results to the same area, keeping away from distortions. Here are my results: http://depthy.me/#/ip/jhGtzbg  If you click on the paint brush, you can see the depth map by cycling through preview. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to extract physical depth values from the disparity map.

Comment: .99 and .7 are somewhat on the high side, though not dramatically so. Does the target cover the field of view and working depth across the set of your calibration images? With significant foreshortening?

Comment: Maybe I just need to try capturing calibration images again with more angles and more extreme foreshortening. I did only capture 19 images for each pose. Maybe I need to do more. The target fits within the frame for each of the images. I should also probably do more work on focusing properly. iOS doesn't allow me to take both images at the same time, so I have to take one, then switch lenses and take the other. I probably need to pause between each lens change and manually check the focus, right now it's automated. I'm attaching an image to my post that is the resulting disparity map.

Comment: can you share your calibration code?  It is difficult to have an opinion without code. Which flags are you using in findChessboard?  are you using cornerSubPix?